# Conditional Formatting with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I was needing some assistance is writing some VBA Code.
I'd like to apply conditional formatting to a table IF the Location Number in Column A matches.

Here is a sample of my table:

```
+-----------------+------+-------+
| Location Number | Year | Value |
+-----------------+------+-------+
|               1 | 2015 | 1.1   |
|               1 | 2016 | 2.3   |
|               2 | 2015 | 2.8   |
|               2 | 2016 | 3.2   |
|               3 | 2015 | 7.8   |
|               3 | 2016 | 3.7   |
+-----------------+------+-------+
```

What I'd like to do is apply conditional formatting to this table so that IF the Location Number matches, then to compare the value from 2015 and 2016.

The conditional formatting is fairly simple:

If 2016 is greater than 2015, turn the value red.

If 2016 is less than 2015, turn the cell green.

Comment: Is the year in column b?

Comment: Correct, the Year is in Column B

Comment: You need to update your question and improve the description of the conditions e.g. (`If 2016 is less than 2015, turn the cell green.`). Also post any VBA you have tried to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following macro:

```
Sub ColorYear()

Dim long1 As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
long1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng)

For t = 2 To long1
If ActiveSheet.Range("A" & t).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & t - 1).Value Then
    If ActiveSheet.Range("C" & t).Value < ActiveSheet.Range("C" & t - 1).Value Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C" & t).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range("C" & t).Value > ActiveSheet.Range("C" & t - 1).Value Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C" & t).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If

    If ActiveSheet.Range("D" & t).Value < ActiveSheet.Range("D" & t - 1).Value Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("D" & t).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range("D" & t).Value > ActiveSheet.Range("D" & t - 1).Value Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("D" & t).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
End If

Next t

End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

If you want to use arrows, you can use the following code:

```
Sub Arrow()

Dim long1 As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
long1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng)

For t = 2 To long1
If ActiveSheet.Range("A" & t).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & t - 1).Value Then

If ActiveSheet.Range("C" & t).Value < ActiveSheet.Range("C" & t - 1).Value Then
ActiveSheet.Range("D" & t).Value = ChrW(9660)
ActiveSheet.Range("D" & t).Font.Color = RGB(42, 154, 68)
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range("C" & t).Value > ActiveSheet.Range("C" & t - 1).Value Then
ActiveSheet.Range("D" & t).Value = ChrW(9650)
ActiveSheet.Range("D" & t).Font.Color = RGB(229, 35, 35)
End If

End If

Next t

End Sub
```

Please note that this code will overwrite the values in column D, so make sure you do not store any values in column D!

Comment: Seems to work! Next question, there are actually multiple "Value" columns. These are in column C, D, E, and F. How can I modify this code to run through each of these columns? So instead of just running in Column C, it would run in Column C, D, E and F?

Comment: You just need to copy the if section (IF to End IF) and paste it below, but within the loop and rename all C's to D's etc.

Comment: Thanks so much, Pete! Just out of curiosity, instead of coloring the cells Red/Green, is there a way to implement the up/down arrow icons? I tried doing this in the standard Conditional Formatting way, but received an error saying Icons can't be applied to relative references...

Comment: Yes, you can use ChrW(9650) and ChrW(9660), but you would need a column where you can enter the values.

Comment: And please don't forget to rate my answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: Sorry Pete, but I'm not sure what you mean by this... How would I modify your code to display a red up arrow and a green down arrow? Similarly what do you mean I need a column to enter the values?

Comment: I just added the code for arrows. Note that the code overwrites the values in column D to add arrows, so make sure you do not store any values in this column!